# Channel Form - attempt to edit and save results in blank page/error

Tags: ee2, channel-form

I'm using EE's Channel Form to allow members to edit entries.

I've isolated the form into a test template and I'm currently not able to successfully submit the form.

When I press save it goes to a blank page. If I go back or refresh Chrome gives me "Confirm Form Resubmission" (with an error ERR_CACHE_MISS).

I've disabled jquery, which got rid of an error appearing in the console but it's still the same result.

Install details:

v2.7.2

Third party modules:

- Zoo Visitor 1.3.30
- Wygwam 3.1.2
- Taxonomy 3.0.8.2
- Playa 4.4.5

Template code:

```
        <html>
        <head>
                <link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
                {!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script> --}
        </head>
        <body>

            {exp:channel:form channel="wiki" return="wiki" url_title="homeworking" rte_selector=".wiki_body" datepicker="no" include_jquery="no"}

                    <h1>{title}</h1>

                    <p>{wiki_body}</p>

                    <input type="text" name="title" class="title" value="{title}">

                    <textarea type="text" name="wiki_body" class="wiki_body">
                    {wiki_body}
                    </textarea>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

            {/exp:channel:form}

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post template code and what version of EE you are using as well as any relevant addons and their versions.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include more details, ta

Comment: What about template code?

Comment: good point, added :)

Comment: Sounds to me that your form is actually submitting correctly and you just don't have anything in your "wiki" template so it's showing as a blank page. How exactly are you testing a "successful" submit? Are you changing data and then looking in the control panel to make sure the data was changed? Is there anything in the "wiki" template which you have set using the return="wiki" parameter?

Comment: Hi Anna. Yes, the wiki template displays the wiki index. It shows correctly when visited normally.

Also, yes, when testing, i've been editing the data and pressing save. Nothing is getting edited in the entries though.

Comment: Fixed! So, I got a colleague to have a deeper look at it and turns out, it was looking for some safecracker db tables (the site was previously updated from 2.5). Something clearly went wrong with the update as there were a few legacy references.

All fixed now. Thanks for your help all.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption here but my guess is that the template code you have shown is for the template wiki. If that is the case you are returning them to a template that can't parse the channel form tags because you aren't passing the need to know information. I have added a conditional that is checking segment 2 for success that i added to your return="wiki/success" and will display a success message. If i had some more info i believe i could solve this problem. such as template code for "wiki" or the page you are originally sending them, and what does the url say after you submit the code below.

```
<html>
        <head>
                <link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
                {!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script> --}
        </head>
        <body>

            {if "{segment_2}" == "success"}
              <h1>Your Submission Was Successful</h1>
            {if:else}
            {exp:channel:form channel="wiki" return="wiki/success" url_title="homeworking" rte_selector=".wiki_body" datepicker="no" include_jquery="no"}

                    <h1>{title}</h1>

                    <p>{wiki_body}</p>

                    <input type="text" name="title" class="title" value="{title}">

                    <textarea type="text" name="wiki_body" class="wiki_body">
                    {wiki_body}
                    </textarea>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

            {/exp:channel:form}
            {/if}
        </body>
        </html>
```